# Can you set the width of excel columns in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I am exporting a DataTable into an excel file with my code below

```
public void ExportGridToExcel(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        string str = "";
       foreach(DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            str += col.ColumnName + "\t";
        }

        foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            str += "\n";
            foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                str += row[col.ColumnName] + "\t";
            }
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.Write(str);
        Response.End();

    }
```

It exports the data into excel fine except one of my columns data gets printed as ###### like this

```
RandomValue         Name                    CreatedDate
0010A               DISPLAY BANNER IF AF    #######
0010B               BANNER ON DRIVER PAG    #######
0018B               NEW CRE BUTTON          #######
0020B               NEW INFO SIDEBAR        #######
0021A               NOT IQ EXPERIENCE       #######
```

but if I were to expand that third column in excel then it shows the values correctly. Is there a way for me to fix this programatically?

Comment: You are building a Tab Delimited *text* file, so not an Excel file at all but a file type Excel happens to be able to open and read.  You cannot include any format information within such a file.

Comment: this is a CSV file with an XLS extension, which Excel is tolerant enough to display. If you need more control, consider an OpenOffice/XML library like for example EPPlus, which will create a real xlsx file with the full set of formatting, styles etc. available.

Comment: I see a lot of people recommending EPPlus, but frankly, using Microsoft's own Interop library to instantiate an Application, then calling the .net classes yourself is just fine.  Use `AutoFit()` once you've got an actual Excel-based file, as opposed to a .csv.